# How to call fragment from IntentService class?

Tags: android

I have a class named '`GeofenceIntentService`' to receive **Push Notification** and I want to call fragment from that class, the class is extends `IntentService` class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to send a message to fragment from the service. You can broadcast the message to fragment by using `Broadcast Receiver`.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you need to open a screen, you should open an **Activity** which contains your **Fragment**, but not a **Fragment** instead.

   For example:

   `Intent i = new Intent();
   i.setClass(GeofenceIntentService.this, HostActivity.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(i);`
2. If you need to communicate between **Service** and **Fragment**, look at [Bound Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) .
3. If you need to send a message to **Fragment** from the Service, use **`BroadcastReceiver`**

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. if we are using **this** in `Fragment` its not find `Activity` context.

We are using **MyFragment.this.getActivity()**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyFragment.this.getActivity(),MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("path",uri);
MyFragment.this.getActivity().startService(intent);
```